# mat-autocomplete: Prevent displaying the old list

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

With the following script I am able to add `<mat-option>` tags:

**HTML**

```html
    <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="onEnter($event)" *ngFor="let data of technologies" [value]="data.technology">
        <span matBadge="{{data.counter}}" matBadgeOverlap="false">{{data.technology}} </span>
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
```

**TS**

```
    // On Key up, show technologies
     onKeyUp(event: any): void {
      if (event.target.value.trim().length > 0) {
        this.technologiesService.getTechnologies(event.target.value)
          .subscribe(data => {
            if (JSON.stringify(this.technologies) !== JSON.stringify(data)) {
              this.technologies = data;
            }
          });
      }
```

**The problem**

If I press a key, I'll get a list of options. If I press another key, the same list (array `technologies`) will be displayed and after about 1 second it disappears and the new list will be shown.

Maybe it needs time, because the new data needs to be sent from the server. But how can I make it display ONLY the new list?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, new list wont be shown until data has arrived. You can set `this.technologies` to an empty array, etc..

And you have two streams here - API call and keyup events. Better merge them into one to have more control on it and the implement other features easier (f.ex. debounceTime, loading animation etc.):

```
@ViewChild('auto', {static: false}) matAutocomplete: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;

fromEvent(this.matAutocomplete.nativeElement, 'keyup').pipe(
  switchMap(event => {
    this.technologies = [];
    return this.technologiesService.getTechnologies(event.target.value)
  })
).subscribe(data => {
  if (JSON.stringify(this.technologies) !== JSON.stringify(data)) {
    this.technologies = data;
  }
})
```

Must use that in `ngAfterViewInit()`, to grab reference to `this.matAutocomplete` (and of course, use @ViewChild() for it).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I get the following error: `TS2345: Argument of type 'MatAutocomplete' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FromEventTarget<unknown>'.
  Property 'length' is missing in type 'MatAutocomplete' but required in type 'ArrayLike<EventTargetLike<unknown>>'.` My ViewChild looks like this: `@ViewChild('auto', {static: false}) matAutocomplete: MatAutocomplete;`

Comment: Added `@ViewChild` decorator, to target ElementRef. And then use `nativeElement` property as target in fromEvent

Comment: I have tried the same but I get the same error: `TS2345: Argument of type 'ElementRef<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FromEventTarget<unknown>'.
  Property 'length' is missing in type 'ElementRef<any>' but required in type 'ArrayLike<EventTargetLike<unknown>>'.`

Comment: Do you import **ElementRef** from  `'@angular/core` and **fromEvent** from `rxjs`?

Comment: Imports should be - `import {  ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';` for Rxjs 6+ version

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in stackblitz.com? Shouldn't be hard in this case

Comment: Sure, you can find the error here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gx6puq

Comment: Oh, ok, `<input>` is not hidden inside `MatAutocomplete` template (in your snippet there is no `<input>` element), so you should bind it to the `<input>` directly. Here i [forked it. Other errors seem not to be related to this issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ka59pq?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Your provided HTML snippet seems to lack some code that belongs to Autocomplete. I assumed there is all there is, so no other than `<mat-autocomplete>` element can listen to all Native Input events. But if you must set `<inpput>` element yourself, there is no need for `<mat-autocomplete>` to receive same events.

Comment: Thank you for the fix. The error is gone now but now I have an error with `event.nativeElement.value` (as you see on Stackblitz). I have tried it with `this.techInput.nativeElement.value` instead. I have no errors anymore but my problem still remains. The old list will still be listed.

Comment: I provided `keyup` event as an example. You should pick native event whichever you need, `event.data` exists on `InputEvent`. And set incomming value type so Typescript could lead you on what properties and methods you can use - `switchMap((event: InputEvent) => {` if you are too lazy to look at the specs ^^. About the old list - can you update the demo to illustrate behaviour?